# Error in UNIX bash script. Syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I'm getting error's in line 16 while trying to execute this bash script. The error's are like this:
line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `then' line 16:`    then muj=`ls -l $fajlli | awk '{print $7}'`'

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f modified ]
then rm modified
fi
touch modified

muajt=`date | awk '{print $2}'`
ditet=`date | awk '{print $3}'`

tegjithafajllet=`ls`

for fajlli in $tegjithafajllet
do
            if[ -f $fajlli ]
16.         then muj=`ls -l $fajlli | awk '{print $7}'`
            dit=`ls -l $fajlli | awk '{print $8}'`
                 if[ $muajt = $muj -a $ditet = $dit ]
                 then echo $fajlli >> modified
                 fi
            fi
done
```

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point out most of the problems here. Also, you should also [avoid parsing the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); use wildcards or `find` to get lists of files, and `stat` to get their properties.

Answer (score 1):

Bash has very strict rule about whitespaces. You need a whitespace after if like `if [ -f $fajlli ]`

Comment: I tried this but still I'm getting the same errors, thank you btw

Comment: @rociG You have made the same mistake in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't close the if statement well

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f modified ]
then rm modified
fi
touch modified

muajt=$(date | awk '{print $2}')
ditet=$(date | awk '{print $3}')

tegjithafajllet=$(ls)
for fajlli in $tegjithafajllet
do
        if [ -f "$fajlli" ]; then
                muj=$(ls -l "$fajlli" | awk '{print $7}')
                dit=$(ls -l "$fajlli" | awk '{print $8}')
        fi
        if [ "$muajt" = "$muj" ] && [ "$ditet" = "$dit" ]; then
                echo "$fajlli" >> modified
        fi
done
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add additional description about how your code works